# Why did Arjuna blame Jayadratha for Abhimanyu's death?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, itihasa, dronacharya, abhimanyu

Why did Arjuna blame Jayadratha for Abhimanyu's death; after all he only did his duty of protecting the formation? If at all, if anyone is to be blamed, it should be Drona who was the commander in chief of the Kaurava Army who by allowing multiple people attacking a single warrior violated the rules of war agreed upon before the start of the war?

Comment: Yes As below answer he misused lord shivas boon and successful in preventing bhimas entry

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be due to Jayadratha using his boon from Lord Shiva for the wrongful cause of murdering his young child. Guru Drona, though a military commander, had no knowledge of this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).